# Is there a way to know if a correct camera preview size will be compatible with the face detector (yield detected faces)

Tags: android, firebase, face-detection, firebase-mlkit

Using the Camera 2 API and Firebase we can detect faces in a preview stream from the camera.
The following snippet is an example of how we can determine a preview size compatible with the camera we want to work with:

```
    Size[] cameraSupportedOutputSizes;

    StreamConfigurationMap map = ch.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
    if(map != null) {
        cameraSupportedOutputSizes = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class);

        List<Size> sizes = Arrays.asList(cameraSupportedOutputSizes);
        Log.e(TAG, Arrays.asList(cameraSupportedOutputSizes).toString());

    }
```

This will yield the following output (for example):

[960x720, 864x480, 640x640, 800x480, 720x480, 768x432, 640x480, 480x640, 576x432, 640x360, 480x360, 480x320, 384x288, 352x288, 320x240, 240x320, 240x160, 176x144, 144x176, 160x120]

Let us say that, wanting to optimize performance, we pick one of the smaller preview sizes, such as 800x480 and configure our Firebase face detector meta like so:

```
            faceDetectorFrameMetadata = new FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.Builder()
                .setRotation(correctRotation)
                .setFormat(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21)
                .setHeight(previewSize.getHeight())
                .setWidth(previewSize.getWidth())
                .build();
```

Now, once we open the camera and start detecting faces we will discover that the face detector is "picky" when it comes to the preview sizes. I can tell you for a fact that for in many instances anything but the largest preview size and several typical preview sizes (such as, but not limited to 1280 x 720 on 16:9 devices, or 1024 x 768 on older 4:3 devices) will allow the correct instantiation of the face detector, but not yield any faces. The face detection task listener will return 0 found faces.

Is there a way to determine which preview sizes will suit the Firebase detector's fancy beforehand?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question!

The underlying model requires a much smaller square image (e.g something like 256 * 256). Before running the model, ML Kit will resize the input image to the smaller size. I guess in some cases, the image after resizing is too distorted to detect faces. It would be nice if you could provide some image example.

In the face detector, it also have a [face size option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/face/FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder#setMinFaceSize(float)) to choose the interested face size. So make sure the face size is big enough to be detected.

Comment: Thank you! This is pointing me in possibly the right direction, however not quite the answer yet. Where did you find the information about the model rescaling square images? Is this done before cropping the face or after? I quite expect the former to be the case.

The face size option you mention is a relative setting and should be independent of the preview size.

Comment: I am from the ML Kit team. We will provide more detailed information about the expected image size in our documents soon. The resizing is done for the whole image before the face detection.

Comment: Wonderful! Your work is extremely appreciated. I will be on the lookout for the updated docs. If there is anything you could share with me in the meanwhile (regarding the optimal preview size to work with ML kit) it would help me in my work.

I am surprised by what you are saying about rescaling the entire image before face detection, because I can successfully get eyeOpenProbability for a person 2 meters away from their device. If the image was, say 256x256 px, there wouldn't be enough pixels to resolve the eyes! :)